# how to create file of type less with php in magento2?

Tags: magento2, php, less

I want to use LESS in Magento 2 with PHP code.

Example: If I want to create CSS with `PHP` in Magento 2, I can create a file `custom.phtml` and then in `XML` I would use `referenceContainer`.

**custom.phtml**

```
<style>
      body{
        color: <?php echo $block->getColor('body') ?>
      }
</style>
```

How can I create a file _theme.less with PHP code like this?

Answer (score 0):

The code you show as your custom.phtml does not generate any CSS file, it's using inline CSS. There is no such thing as "inline LESS" because LESS needs to be preprocessed to be converted do PHP.

But you ***could*** use the preprocessor directly, mimicking [Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Processor](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/f748e57d04f65cb0b6f3d22cfc00602e6772e51d/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Css/PreProcessor/Adapter/Less/Processor.php) without actually reading from files:

1. Inject `Magento\Framework\Css\PreProcessor\File\Temporary` in your block (I assume you know how to use the Magento 2 DI framework)

   ```
   /** @var Magento\Framework\Css\PreProcessor\File\Temporary */
   protected $temporaryFile;
   ```
2. Create a method like this in your block

   ```
   public function getCss($content) 
   {
       $path = 'tmp.css';
       try {
           $parser = new \Less_Parser(
               [
                   'relativeUrls' => false,
                   'compress' => $this->_appState->getMode() !== State::MODE_DEVELOPER
               ]
           );
           if (trim($content) === '') {
               return '';
           }
           $tmpFilePath = $this->temporaryFile->createFile($path, $content);
           $parser->parseFile($tmpFilePath, '');
           $content = $parser->getCss();
           if (trim($content) === '') {
               $errorMessage = PHP_EOL . self::ERROR_MESSAGE_PREFIX . PHP_EOL . $path;
               $this->_logger->critical($errorMessage);
               throw new \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\ContentProcessorException(new Phrase($errorMessage));
           }
           return $content;
       } catch (\Exception $e) {
           $errorMessage = PHP_EOL . self::ERROR_MESSAGE_PREFIX . PHP_EOL . $path . PHP_EOL . $e->getMessage();
           $this->_logger->critical($errorMessage);
           throw new \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\ContentProcessorException(new Phrase($errorMessage));
       }
   }
   ```
3. Output this CSS in the template:

   ```
   <style><?php echo $block->getCss('

      LESS GOES HERE

   '); ?></style>
   ```